# How to pass data dynamically to mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have following query,

```
SELECT t_subject.subject, SUM( t_skilllist.skill_level ) AS total_skill, t_users.first_name, 

t_skilllist.skill_level
FROM  `t_skilllist` 
JOIN t_subject ON t_subject.id = t_skilllist.subject_id
JOIN t_users ON t_users.id = t_skilllist.user_id
WHERE t_subject.subject =  'html'
GROUP BY t_users.first_name
ORDER BY total_skill DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I want to display subject and skill level for each student. But, for one subject I can do that with above query. As an example for html it works. However, I want to pass more than one subject to the query dynamically. I tried to combined subjects with AND operator but it return empty result set.

How to solve this? How to pass more than two subjects to the query? I am using PHP as server side scripting language.

Comment: use OR instead of AND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) clause.

```
WHERE t_subject.subject IN ('html', 'php', 'and', 'a', 'lot', 'more')
```